# How to avoid high GPU usage when calling SDL_GL_SwapWindow when using an OpenGL context?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, sdl, glew

I'm getting a strange behaviour where the GPU usage gets very high and sometimes just stays below 2%.

Right now I'm using an OpenGL context to make draw calls, you can see the code I'm using to reproduce this bug right here:

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <string>

static const int DEFAULT_WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280;
static const int DEFAULT_WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720;

int main() {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

#ifdef __APPLE__
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS,
                      SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_FLAG);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
#endif

  SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl");
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

  SDL_Window *window =
      SDL_CreateWindow(nullptr, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                       DEFAULT_WINDOW_WIDTH, DEFAULT_WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                       SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);

  SDL_GLContext glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit();

  SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, glcontext);
  SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  SDL_Event event;

  bool quit = false;
  while (!quit) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
      quit = SDL_QUIT == event.type;
    }

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
  }

  SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glcontext);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

I isolated this down to just the SDL_GL_SwapWindow call, if you look at the screenshot you can see it's taking 26% of GPU usage just on its own. This is random, if I wait a couple of hours and come back de GPU usage will be around 2%.

I closed all other applications and processes to check this is not happening when other apps are open.

I tried switching GLEW and SDL for GLAD and GLFW and I still get the same result. All this is in macos catalina 10.15.7

Is this normal?

Comment: Do you have vsync enabled?

Comment: yes https://github.com/ellipticaldoor/sdl-opengl-high-gpu-usage-bug/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L34

Comment: What happens if you put a `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` the the begnning of the loop? Also what GPU are you using (Intel per chance? The Intel drivers are weird).

Comment: But this is the only GL call in the game loop, how it can take 25% of the GPU?

Comment: @ellipticaldoor: The problem is, that `SwapBuffers` isn't strictly part of OpenGL, but the window system. And without actual OpenGL commands being queued up, something weird may happen with the swap chain. Add that `glClear`; that gives you one nice OpenGL command against which the swap chain can be fenced with; also most OpenGL implementations take `glClear` as the indication of a new frame being started.

Comment: I added glClear and the beginning of the loop but still I get the same result

Comment: @datenwolf I'm using an Intel Iris Plus Graphics 1536 MB

Comment: My suspicion remains that vsync is not being correctly turned on/respected. It's something that has historically been flaky on the Mac. I would add some timers to manually check the framerate

Comment: the framerate is locked to 60fps, I'm using a function to measure that but I didn't included it on the code above just to simplify